# Determine '\' position in string

Tags: nant

I'm trying to get the directory name from a path string using nant. However, whenever I use the following:

```
<property name="lastBackSlash" value="${string::last-index-of('${foldername}', '\')}" />
```

... this returns -1. I am sure the foldername contains a path with backslashes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`directory::get-parent-directory()`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/directory.get-parent-directory.html)?

Comment: What I need to do is to loop over a set of folder and do something with the directory name, not the path. So I do a foreach folder, and then use the property foldername, which contains the folderpath. From that I need to extract the directory name, which does not work with path::get-directory-name...

Comment: Did you try to use: "\\" ?

Comment: Yes, keeps returning -1. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many dollar signs, assuming of course, that foldername is a property.

```
<property name="lastBackSlash" value="${string::last-index-of(foldername, '\')}" />
```